# neural network predicting same output class for every input while training also

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, backpropagation

I'm implementing a neural network using backpropogation algorithm in python.the method used is similar to that taught by Andrew Ng in his Machine Learning course.
But the NN is predicting same class and nearly similar values for every input while training and testing.For every input set the output class with highest probability is same.

I've tried adding bias units,normalising inputs,regularisation. Nothing seems to work.The method used is similar to that taught by Andrew Ng and i've used vectorization for operations.

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:,:]
Y = iris.target 
a=np.amax(X,axis=0)#column wise maximum of input data
b=np.amin(X,axis=0)#column wise minimum
for row in X:#divide each values by difference of max-min for that column
    row[0]=row[0]/(a[0]-b[0])
    row[1]=row[1]/(a[1]-b[1])
    row[2]=row[2]/(a[2]-b[2])
    row[3]=row[3]/(a[3]-b[3])
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, 
test_size=0.3, 
                                                random_state=1)

biasa2=np.random.rand(5,1) #defining bias nodes for hidden layer a2
biasa3=np.random.rand(3,1) #defining bias nodes for output layes a3

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z)) #returns sigmoid of given array

def gradient_descent(theta,delta):
    num_iterations=50000
    learning_rate=.07
    for i in range(0,num_iterations):
    t    heta=np.subtract(theta,(learning_rate*delta)/2)

    return theta


def back_prop():
    a1=zeros([4,1])#input layer
    a2=zeros([5,1])#hidden layer
    a3=zeros([3,1])#output layer
    theta1=np.random.rand(5,4) #input to hidden layer weights
    theta2=np.random.rand(3,5) #hidden t output layer weights

    #print(theta1)
    #print(theta2)
    delta1=zeros([5,4]) #diffrential of cost function wrt every 
    #weight in input to hidden layer
    delta2=zeros([3,5]) #diffrential of cost function in hidden to 
    #output layer
    for i in range(0,len(X_train)):
        y=zeros([3,1]) #store expected output for input
        a1=X_train[i,:] #input matrix
        a1= a1.reshape(len(X_train[i]),1)

        #a1=a1/np.amax(a1,axis=0)
        print("a1 is")
        print(a1)
        z=np.matmul(theta1,a1)#
        z=z+biasa2
        a2=sigmoid(z) #hidden layer node values
        #a2=z
        a2=a2.reshape(len(a2),1)
        print("a2 is ")
        print(z)
        a2[0,0]=1
        z=np.matmul(theta2,a2)
        z=z+biasa3
        a3=sigmoid(z) #output layer values
        #a3=z
        a3=a3.reshape(len(a3),1)
        print("a3 is ")
        print(z)
        y[Y_train[i],0]=1 #setting index with output to 1,rest are 
        zero

        prev_del=np.subtract(y,a3) #expected -current output
        prev_del=np.multiply(prev_del,np.multiply(a3,1- 
        a3)) #multipling with diffrential
        #print("Error in output is")
        #print(prev_del)
        temp=np.matmul(prev_del,a2.transpose())
        delta2=np.add(delta2,temp) #calculating diffrential for layer  
        #2
        _del=np.matmul(theta2.transpose(),prev_del) #calculating error 
        #for layer 2
        temp2=ones([5,1])
        temp2=np.subtract(temp2,a2)
        _del=np.multiply(_del,np.multiply(temp2,a2)) #error of layer 2
        delta1=np.add(delta1,np.matmul(_del,a1.transpose()))
       #diffrential for hidden layer

    d1=zeros([5,4]) #array to store final diffrentiation of cost 
    wrt hidden layer weights
    d2=zeros([3,5]) #array to store final diffrentiation of cost 
    wrt output layer weights
    lmbda=.004#regularization parameter
    d1=(delta1+lmbda*theta1)/len(X_train)
    d2=(delta2+lmbda*theta2)/len(X_train)
    theta=hstack((theta1.flatten(),theta2.flatten())) #flattening 
    #theta matrices for gradient descent
    delta=hstack((d1.flatten(),d2.flatten())) #flattening delta 
    #matrices for gd
    theta= gradient_descent(theta,delta)
    #print(theta)
    return theta #return final theta values after training data
```

if in run the code and print matrices a1,a2,a3 in every iteration of training loop,the index in output class with highest value is same for every input.Sometimes a3[0] is highest for every input sometimes a3[2] is highest.
these are values of matrices without applying sigmoid function.

Comment: The first for loop in the back_prop() function is the training loop.I'm using the same loop to first calculate node values for different layers(matrices a2,a3) and then in the second part of loop I'm calculating errors and delta values(prev_del,_del,delta1,delta2 are for this purpose).After the for loop i used gradient descent to minimise cost function.